# executorservice to read data from database in chuncks and run process on them

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to write a process that would read data from a database and upload it onto a cloud datastore.

How can I decide the partition strategy of the data? I want to query the table in chunks and process each chunk in 10 threads. Each thread basically will send the data to an individual node on a 10 node cluster on the cloud..

Where in the below multi threading code will the dataquery to extract and send 10 concurrent requests for uploading data to cloud would be? Its very important I do not loose the cursor for what my database query has processed thus far incase of failure, so in the database once a batch of 100 records have been processed for example, it should update those record statuses from PENDING to DONE in the database column for that record. This job will run every 10 min to pull data from a source database.

```
public class Caller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Runnable worker = new DomainCDCProcessor(i);
                executor.execute(worker);
              }
            executor.shutdown();
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            }
            System.out.println("Finished all threads");
        }


    }
```

Comment: I would do a sort of round-robin. The question seems little ambiguous though.

Comment: Is this a "once only" process, or something that runs periodically?

Comment: I don't think keeping the cursor is a good idea. Add ORDER BY to your query instead and keep last processed id (or timestamp, or some more unique field). On the next query set limit or add condition like WHERE ID>lastProcessedId

Answer (score 0):

Do a select before starting the workers to determine the set or range (first ID - last ID) of all the primary IDs of the records to process. Give each worker a sub-set or range-part to work with. Make sure the workers never go outside there given set or range.

Comment: Thank you vanOekel, Are there any examples that I can use? Any code that I can read to understand how to use executors with database? THANK YOU!